# Jenkins Visual Studio x64 prompt (for CMake and Ninja)

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, cmake, jenkins-pipeline, ninja

I have a Jenkins slave with Visual Studio 2012 and want to build for x64. What I need is the prompt environment I get when I run the tools prompt link in the Windows Start Menu. People suggest to do it like this (in a Jenkins Windows Batch prompt):

```
call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" x86_amd64
```

But this is not enough. There are small differences in the `PATH`, `LIB` and `LIBPATH` environment variables: the paths in there point to the x32 paths only, e.g. to

```
...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN;...
```

instead of

```
...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN;...
```

In fact I am trying to build with the Ninja generator from CMake where the build configuration is determined by the prompt environment.

Comment: It's pretty ugly, but you could try `call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vsvarsall.bat" x86_amd64` (or using a better method of locating the `VC` directory where `vcvarsall.bat` is located).

Comment: Nice, this works! This is the answer to my question.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution, and can run vsvarsall.bat for my Visual Studio version; in that 'execute windows batch command` box I also execute 'cl' and it works. But I use the use 'CMake integration plugin' to then run CMake and it fails to find the compiler; I guess because it does not inherit the preceding environment. Is there a way to resolve this? I don't really want to have invoke cmake manually in the batch step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64` which is located in the `VC`-subdirectory (and [eventually remove parentheses](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11992?focusedCommentId=210554&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-210554) from the `PATH`):

```
set path=%path:"=%
call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
```

If you want to run this in a Pipeline script:

```
bat """set path=%path:\"=%
       call "%vs110comntools%..\\..\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64
       ..."""
```